# Connecting two antennas to provide signal

Tags: waves, resonance, antennas

Problem:

I am in a room without FM signal. I would like to provide FM signal to the room.

If you have a hole for coaxial cable, which can connect a place with signal and the room, is it possible to use the following solution, considering that Antenna1 and Antenna2 are same.

[image: Problem image]

Comment: I would guess you're hoping that the external aerial will convert the radio wave to an electrical signal, and the internal aerial will convert the electrical signal back into a radio wave. So the end result is that the radio wave is piped into your room. Is this correct?

Comment: @JohnRennie That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

(1) How does Antenna1 "know" that it is supposed to be transmitting and not receiving?

(2) Even if Antenna1 and Antenna2 knew their roles, then the power Antenna2 gets is tiny. When that power gets reradiated from Antenna1 then the power is teeny tiny.

Two ways.

First you could have a "repeater." It picks up the signal at Antenna2 and retransmits it through antenna1. This is an active device not a passive one. But such a repeater will only work for one frequency.

Second choice to to run cable from whatever device you want to use to what you have as antenna 2.

Comment: Both of your initial statements are wrong. Antennas don't have "directions" (this follows from time reversal invariance of Maxwell's equations) and if the antenna impedances are matched and the connection is done by a matched cable, then all the received power from one antenna will be re-radiated by the other. It is true that a small antenna on the outside can't power another antenna to fill the entire room with enough field strength to be useful, but that's because of the relative effective field volumes, not because of your arguments.

Comment: As to (1) yes I agree that antennas don't have directions. That was the point that I was trying to make. I was just thinking that if I tapped the cable in the middle of the two antennas system that there would be more noise than if just the external antenna was used.

Comment: (2) When antenna-1 "picks" up the radiowaves it creates a current in the antenna. If the impedances were matched then due the nature of electrical circuits the same current would flow in antenna-2. Antenna-2 then emits radiowaves at a lower power. So antenna-2 doesn't emit as much electromagnetic power as antenna-1 receives. You are right that the answer fails to mention antenna3, the antenna on the radio. The power transfer from antenna2 to antenna3 will be much less efficient than the power transfer of the electromagnetic radiation received by antenna-1 and transmitted by antenna 2.

Comment: While this may be counterintuitive, with matched impedance the scenario that you have in mind doesn't happen. All the energy goes one way. It's only in the case of impedance mismatch that reflections reduce transmitted power. While the antenna to antenna scenario may make it harder to intuitively approach the problem, you could imagine cutting the cable and inserting a unity gain amplifier. Then analyze the reflections on the input and output of that amplifier for the perfectly matched case.

Comment: If I put 1 watt of electrical power into an antenna isn't it correct that I don't get 1 watt of electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: A properly matched antenna will radiate 1W. The power can only go two places, either into the air or back into the transmitter in form of reflections, everything else between is just metal that won't get hot (at least not substantially). I do understand your reservations about this, by the way. I didn't develop an intuition for antenna matching until I had the chance to work with an HP4195 vector analyzer, which can show you the transmitted and reflected power as a function of frequency in real time and things change when you screw around with the antenna geometry. That's awesome!

Comment: My understanding was that matching the impedance maximizes the efficiency of transmission. I don't think that any antenna is 100% efficient. I'm thinking more like 40-50% is the best that you could do. // You're absolutely right that the "lost" energy isn't heating the antenna. Since the signal has to go to the end of the antenna and back then the reflection has a "time delay". So what you're trying to do is setup a standing wave. That only works for one frequency. Can you impedance match for multiple frequencies at once??

Comment: Yes, perfectly matched antennas are 100% efficient. They are not thermodynamic machines and there is no equivalent of the Carnot limit to antenna efficiency. One can always design an antenna very carefully and tune it with lumped elements or tuning screws etc. to have near perfect efficiency. Nobody goes much beyond 90-99%, though, technically that makes no appreciable difference. I am sorry to say but your intuition is simply wrong on this one. One can build wideband antennas that are efficient over entire ranges. A good example of that would be horn and parabolic antennas.

Comment: I just don't see how an antenna could be 100% efficient. If that were true then transformers could be made 100% efficient and that doesn't happen. When the HP4195 vector analyzer read 100% then you get a perfect standing wave. I think of it like "shaking" a rope up and down that has one end tied to a wall. If you shake it just right you get a standing wave and can get a nice rhythm going with your hand motion. Otherwise the reflection from the wall will cause the rope to twitch at your end.

Comment: You can see that by either doing the measurements or by doing the math with reflection and transmission coefficients. Transformers can be made near 100% efficient, too, technically nobody cares, though because of diminishing returns. You can, for instance, take a crappy broadband transformer and improve its performance by making both sides resonant. That's a well known trick and it is currently being used quite successfully with wireless chargers for cell phones. The vector analyzer measures real transmission and reflection and it's very precise (certainly better than 1% when calibrated).

Comment: No problem. I hope you can get your hands on a vector analyzer. The HP4195 was a real workhorse and one can buy them now for less than $5000. If my better half wouldn't kill me, I would pick one of those babies up today. :-)